# Find number of common elements between two lists or hashsets with millions of elements

Tags: c#

What are some performant ways to determine the number of common elements between two lists or hashsets, which may have millions of values, in c#?

Comment: Maybe a solution involving LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best performance is going to be available with HashSets. You can use the [IntersectWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx) method.

```
// assuming HashSet<T> hashSetA
//     and an IEnumerable<T> collectionB
hashSetA.IntersectWith(collectionB);
```

The hashset-based solution gives O(n) performance which is pretty much as good as it gets.

The next best thing would be to sort the two lists and then iterate linearly in lock-step over the two lists, selecting the common elements, which yeilds O(nlogn) performance.

Answer (score 1):

HashSet IntersectWith

[HashSet.IntersectWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx)

For comparing two List I would create HashSet of the larger

[HashSet Constructor (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Except**

[Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: I believe you have the functions confused with Java.. The question is about C#.

Comment: But We can use retainAll and Except  in c#

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just not following. The `retainAll` function is not defined on any BCL class in .NET..