# Compare and merge two List<T> into new List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list, compare, iequalitycomparer

I'm trying to figure out how best to compare and merge two `List<T>` with a new `List<T>` being generated that compares multiple properties within each object.

```
class Account
{
    public Account() { }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<Account> Mine = new List<Account>();
List<Account> Yours = new List<Account>();
List<Account> Ours = new List<Account>();

Account m1 = new Account(){ ID = null, Name = "C_First", Value = "joe" };
Account m2 = new Account(){ ID = null, Name = "C_Last", Value = "bloggs" };
Account m3 = new Account(){ ID = null, Name = "C_Car", Value = "ford" };

Mine.Add(m1);
Mine.Add(m2);
Mine.Add(m3);

Account y1 = new Account(){ ID = "1", Name = "C_First", Value = "john" };
Account y2 = new Account(){ ID = "2", Name = "C_Last", Value = "public" };

Yours.Add(y1);
Yours.Add(y2);
```

The resulting `List<Account> Ours` would have the following `List<Account>` objects:

```
{ ID = "1", Name = "C_First", Value = "joe" };
{ ID = "2", Name = "C_Last", Value = "bloggs" };
{ ID = null, Name = "C_Car", Value = "ford" };
```

I need to figure out how best to compare the ID and Value properties between both `List<Account>` objects where the `List<Account> Yours` ID takes precedence over the `List<Account> Mine` and the `List<Account> Mine` Value takes precedence over `List<Account> Yours` along with any object that's not in `List<Account> Yours` being added as well.

I've tried the following:

```
Ours = Mine.Except(Yours).ToList();
```

which results in `List<Ours>` being empty.

I've read this post [Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists) in which Jon Skeet mentions using a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` to do what I need but I'm stuck on how to create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that compares more than 1 property value.

Comment: How do you define that two items represent the same but with different data? is just by name and value?

Comment: By the Name property, so if the objects name properties are the same but the Value is different from one object to the other the List<Account> Mine would take precedence but the ID of List<Account> Yours would override the null value for ID in the List<Account> Mine. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done in "pue" LINQ, but a bit of procedural code would do the trick:

```
var dict = Yours.ToDictionary(y => y.Name);
foreach (var m in Mine) {
    Account y;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(m.Name, out y))
        Ours.Add(new Account { ID = y.ID, Name = m.Name, Value = m.Value });
    else
        Ours.Add(m);
}
```

After that, printing `Ours`...

```
foreach (var o in Ours)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", o.ID, o.Name, o.Value);
```

...gives the following result:

```
1       C_First joe
2       C_Last  bloggs
        C_Car   ford
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep it from adding objects with the same Name and Value?Account m4 = new Account(){ ID = null, Name = "C_Hair", Value = "long" }; Account y3 = new Account(){ ID = "1", Name = "C_Hair", Value = "long" };

Comment: @devinM.arnold If I understood correctly what you wish to accomplish, you'll need to create a "key" class that combines `Name` and `Value`, and then use _it_ as the dictionary key (instead of the string). Just be careful to properly implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) - override `GetHashCode`.

Comment: adding brackets around the if statement then adding this conditional did the trick (y.Value != m.Value)

Comment: that makes perfect sense about creating a separate "key" class, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var index = Mine.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

foreach(var account in Yours)
{
    if(index.ContainsKey(account.Name))
    {
        var item = index[account.Name]; 
        if(item.ID == null)
            item.ID = account.ID;
    }
    index.Add(account.Name, account);
}

Ours = index.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: Intellisense is saying that the last x in (x => x.Name, x) doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Fixed. Also, the code is just for giving an idea of a possible solution, you have to put a little bit of effort

Comment: enough `Mine.ToDictionary(x=>x.Name)`

Comment: Kept getting an exceptionerror regarding duplicate keys ivowiblo

Comment: Grundy, that sort of worked but the ID values were all null in the resulting Dictionary

Comment: That's why you need to execute the foreach on the Yours list for getting the IDs for those values who have null ID.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for IEqualityComparer:

```
public class D : IEqualityComparer<Account>
{
    public bool Equals(Account x, Account y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID && x.Value==y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Account obj)
    {
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

used like this:
`Ours = Mine.Except(Yours, new D()).ToList();`

Comment: Is it used like this: Mine.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, new D());