# how to get the difference of two list<> objects ?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2008

i generate a list of an Object called Exceptions :

```
public class Exceptions
{
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime OriginalDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndUtc { get; set; }
    public Int32 NumParticipants { get; set; }
    public String Subject { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }
}
```

List A got 2 Objects and List B got 3 Objects

I Expect a new List which shows me the difference between the two objects

i tried it with the following function:

```
var ListC = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();
```

i get two objects in ListC which looks exactly like ListA.But i Expected the missing Object from List B.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you provided a custom implementation of `Equals` for your `Exceptions` class?  If not, it will do reference comparisons.

Comment: The missing `Equals`/`GetHashCode` methods aside, if you expect the "missing" object from list B, it should be `ListB.Except(ListA)`, not otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: @sloth i get 3 objects when i do it the other way

Comment: @ErayGeveci Unsurprisingly. You still have to implement `Equals`/`GetHashCode` or an `IEqualityComparer<Exceptions>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expect` uses a default equality comparer to compare your objects which compares them by *reference*.you need to implement a custom equality comparer and use that comparer with Except method.

You can find example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you don't know how to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your type.

Comment: how can i do it when i have two lists? in your example it compares two single objects. could you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
var ListC = ListA.Except(ListB).Union(ListB.Except(ListA))
```

Comment: when i add your solution, i get 5 results instead of one

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` so that the comparison is as you'd expect.

```
public class Exceptions
{
   public override bool Equals(object o)
   {
      return this.Equals(o as Exceptions);
   }

   public bool Equals(Exceptions ex)
   {
       if(ex == null)
          return false;
       else
       {
           // Do comparison here
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A **Linq alternative**, there could be a much faster approach:
HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith():

```
var exceptions = new HashSet(listA);

exceptions.SymmetricExceptWith(listB);
```