# C# Linq EF6, Compare 2 lists, add/remove difference

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application. I use Entity Framework 6.

I want to compare 2 lists and add/remove the difference to my collection using Entity Framework 6. I'm looking for a way to get the new items from **currentList** and add them to the **originalList** afterwards. My C# looks as follows:

```
var originalOffer = MyDb.Offer.First(o => o.OfferId == model.OfferId);

    if (originalOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPool.Delivery.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentList = model.DeliveryModelId.Select(x => new Delivery {DeliveryModelId = x}).ToList();

        var originalList = originalOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPool.Delivery.ToList();

            //... originalOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPool.Delivery. Add or delete the difference here


     }

MyDb.SaveChanges();
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue with EF 6?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx); using `A.Except(B)` will give you a list of everything in A not in B and using `B.Except(A)` vice versa. Using `A.Intersect(B)` will give you everything in A *and* b.

In your specific situation ([thanks @stuartd for pointing it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213004/c-sharp-linq-compare-2-lists-and-get-difference/43213056?noredirect=1#comment73497871_43213056)) you need an EqualityComparer (so implement an [`IEqualityComparer<Delivery>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you haven't done so already) for `Delivery`; you can use the overloads that allow you to specify an equalitycomparer ([`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Instead of an EqualityComparer you could also override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` in your `Delivery` class.

Comment: All those methods will require an equality comparer to be defined for `Delivery`, either explicitly or by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Comment: @stuartd Only if you care about value equality; type reference equality can be OK too in some situations.

Comment: Not in this situation - `Select(x => new Delivery {DeliveryModelId = x})` will create new references..

Comment: @stuartd Ah, crap. Missed that. You are correct. (btw. my name is RobIII ⇒ roman numeral 3 )

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately I forgot to mention, I use Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var list = currentList.Except(originalList).ToList();
```

Comment: `Except` will require an equality comparer to be defined for `Delivery`, either explicitly or by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Comment: Thanks for your help though