# Compare a property of an object in 2 lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following (simplified) class:

```
public class CareRate {

  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public decimal DayRate { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to compare two lists of `CareRate` only by their `DayRate`; one with `CareRates` containing the current `DayRates` and one with `CareRates` containing the `DayRates` to update. Other properties which might have changed like Description, should not be taken into account.

```
// Just a test method
public List<CareRate> FilterChangedCareRates(){
    var currentCareRates = new List<CareRate>{
        new CareRate { Id = 1, DayRate = 3,33, Description = "Some descr" }, 
        new CareRate { Id = 2, DayRate = 4,44, Description = "Some other descr" } 
    };

    var updatedCareRates = new List<CareRate>{
        new CareRate { Id = 1, DayRate = 2,22 }, 
        new CareRate {Id = 2, DayRate = 4,44 } // Unchanged
   };

    var actualUpdatedCareRates = new List<CareRate>();

    foreach(var updatedCareRate in updatedCareRates) {
        var currentCareRate = currentCareRates.Single(x => x.Id == updatedCareRate.Id); 
        if (updatedCareRate.DayRate != currentCareRate.DayRate) {
            actualUpdatedCareRates.Add(updatedCareRate); 
        }
    }
    return actualUpdatedCareRates;
}
```

The manner to filter the changed `CareRate` objects by `Dayrate`, feels a bit devious. I think I am overlooking something. What other and better options are there for acquiring the above?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you want to do with the lists you speak of.. are you just after a list of items where the rate changed, or an updated list of all the original items wth new rates?

Comment: Seems like a review. Should probably go to CodeReview.StachExchange.com

Comment: @BugFinder would like to have a new list of CareRate that only have a changed DayRate (compared to the current DayRate).

Comment: You can do this in one line: `return updatedCareRates.Where(updated => currentCareRates.Any(current => current.DayRate != updated.DayRate))`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Codereview.stackexchange.com, yes. The non-simplified version would be preferred over there, please refer to the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @S.Akbari I have posted an answer. I created a comparer to use in the `Except` extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method in LINQ:

```
var actualUpdatedCareRates = currentCareRates.Zip(updatedCareRates, 
                             (f, s) => f.DayRate != s.DayRate ? s : null)
                             .Where(c => c != null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use something like this:

```
updatedCareRates.ForEach(x =>
{
    if (currentCareRates.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.Id && y.DayRate != x.DayRate) != null)
        actualUpdatedCareRates.Add(x);
});
```

Or in one line:

```
updatedCareRates.Where(x => currentCareRates.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.Id &&
                            y.DayRate != x.DayRate) != null).ToList()
                           .ForEach(x => actualUpdatedCareRates.Add(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
return (from up in updatedCareRates
            join cur in currentCareRates
            on up.Id equals cur.Id
            where up.DayRate != cur.DayRate
            select up).ToList();
```

Here is one of the rare cases where I think Query syntax is better than Method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `Where(x => x...)`, I looked for a solution with using the `Except` method as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636486/3652378).

I created a class `DayRateComparer` as showed below.

```
public class DayRateComparer : IEqualityComparer<CareRate>
{
    public bool Equals(CareRate x, CareRate y) {
        if (x = null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));
        if (y = null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(y));

        return x.Id == y.Id && x.DayRate == y.DayRate;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CareRate obj) {
        retun obj.Id.GetHashCode() + obj.DayRate.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}
```

And I used the `DayRateComparer` like this:

```
// Just a test method
public List<CareRate> FilterChangedCareRates(){
    var currentCareRates = new List<CareRate>{
        new CareRate { Id = 1, DayRate = 3,33, Description = "Some descr" }, 
        new CareRate { Id = 2, DayRate = 4,44, Description = "Some other descr" } 
    };

    var updatedCareRates = new List<CareRate>{
        new CareRate { Id = 1, DayRate = 2,22 }, 
        new CareRate {Id = 2, DayRate = 4,44 } // Unchanged
   };

    return updatedCareRates.Except(currentCareRates, new DayRateComparer()).ToList();
}
```

I don't like the use of a temporary list (like `actualUpdatedCareRates`) and this is not necessary anymore when using a comparer. The `Zip` method as mentioned by [@S.Akbari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159932/2946329) is also a clean and short way but looks a bit complex for me at first sight. Thanks all for your posts.

Comment: No `Zip` is not complex as you think. Just go and read how does it works in the link that I've mentioned in my answer. It makes your works a lot easier than writing a comparer for this purpose while you can easily use `Zip` method IMO.

Comment: @S.Akbari, you are right. It isn't that complex and it does what it should do. I marked your answer as the solution.