# Difference between custom list and string list

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 list, first one is a string list which I fill with `Directory.GetFiles()` method and my second list is a custom one. I have only 2 fields in my custom list. First one is `FilePath` second is `UniqueID`..
What I try to achieve is, I want to compare the string list with my custom list's `FilePath` field. I need to get the changes.

I've convert my Custom list to string and tried this solution 
[Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)
It worked perfect but in my case it's useless for me. I need to compare different type of lists

Here is my custom class that I'm using as model

```
public class IndexerListModel
{
    public string FilePath = string.Empty;
    public string uniqueID = string.Empty;
}
```

And this is how I tried it already

```
List<IndexerListModel> T3 = XMLList.Except(WinFileList, new PathComparer()).ToList();
```

But because I don't use the same type on my list's it did not worked.

I was expecting to get the difference like a new list that show me these "x" items inside your list have different Filepaths..

My overall goal is getting the changes in a windows folder on Application start. So I will know which files has been added/removed/changed/renamed while my application was not up

Comment: `var differentFilePaths = customList.Where(c => !stringList.Contains(c.FilePath));`

Comment: You can use `Select` to project the string property that you want to compare. Then `Except` works but you get a `List<string>`. Otherwise you could use this approach: `XMLList.Where(x => !WinFileList.Contains(x.FilePath)).ToList()`

Comment: List<IndexerListModel> differentFilePaths = XMLList.Where(c => !WinFileList.Contains(c.FilePath)).ToList(); this gave me the list of deleted files which I should delete from my XML too to keep it updated. and if I remove the "!" which gives me the list that I should check carefully if the contect of the file changed so far okay, how can I get the list for files that has been added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly the custom `<List<IndexerListModel>` will contain the content of a directory Eg `C:\Windows` .

We will then use `var myPathList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows").ToList();` to retrieve the content of a `C:\Windows` when the application starts.

The result would be a list of paths that is not contained in our custom `<List<IndexerListModel>`

If the above assumption is correct I have come up with this solution:

```
public class IndexerListModel
{
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myPathList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows").ToList();

        List<IndexerListModel> myModelList = new List<IndexerListModel> {
            new IndexerListModel {
            UniqueID= "0001",
            FilePath = @"C:\Windows\bfsvc.exe"
        },
            new IndexerListModel {
            UniqueID= "0002",
            FilePath = @"C:\Windows\diagwrn.xml"
        }
        };

        var result = myPathList.Where(path => !myModelList.Any(model => model.FilePath == path)).ToList();
    }
}
```

When I run the application I have a total of 27 files in my `C:\Windows`.
- result will evaluate to a List of 25 items. That implies that a total of 25 files have been added since last execution.

We can update  List myModelList in order to reflect the changes in `C:\Windows`. I would imagine that `myModelList` be saved in a db or file in order to be persistent.

Comment: Yes thank you that was the other half I needed to complete what I try to achieve. With that result variable I can get the files that has been add to folder while my application was not open. And for the other half I used List<IndexerListModel> UniqueIDCheckList = XMLList.Where(c => !WinFileList.Contains(c.FilePath)).Reverse().ToList(); which gives me the list of deleted files. Now I can update my XML file everytime when my application starts correctly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a left outer join

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication98
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> WinFileList = Directory.GetFiles("AllDirectories[i]", ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            List<IndexerListModel> models = new List<IndexerListModel>();

            //use left outer join
            var results = (from w in WinFileList
                           join m in models on w equals m.FilePath into wm
                           from m in wm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { model = m, windFileList = w }).ToList();


        }
    }
    public class IndexerListModel : IEqualityComparer<IndexerListModel>
    {
        public string FilePath = string.Empty;
        public string uniqueID = string.Empty;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I change my class as you say will I be able to use Except to get differences between my Custom type list and my string type list?

Comment: My code is verifying two properties FilePath and uniqueID while the code posted was only testing one property.  I do not know what format your string list looks like.  I would think you need to make it a class.

Comment: This is how I fill my string list 
    WinFileList = Directory.GetFiles(AllDirectories[i], "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

`models.Except(models.Where(y=> strings.Contains(y.FilePath)));`