# Custom IEqualityComparer to calculate Difference between two lists using LINQ Except

Tags: c#, linq, comparator

I am using this answer [Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists) to find a difference between two lists using Linq `Except`. However, my objects in the lists are of generic type, so I wrote a Comparer for the generic types, then I pass it to Except method. However I receive the following error message:

> Error CS1929  **'List' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload** 'ParallelEnumerable.Except(ParallelQuery, ParallelQuery, IEqualityComparer)' **requires a receiver of type** 'ParallelQuery'

My call:

```
var differenceList = list1.Except(list2, new PropertyComparer<Guid>("ObjectId"));
```

And my comparer:

```
public class PropertyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private PropertyInfo _PropertyInfo;
    public PropertyComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        _PropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, 
            BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (_PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("{0} is not a property of type {1}.", propertyName, typeof(T)));
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        object propertyValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return propertyValue.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        object xValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
        object yValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(y, null);

        if (xValue == null)
        {
            return yValue == null;
        }

        return xValue.Equals(yValue);
    }
}
```

And from the declaration of Except method in `System.Linq`, which fits my comparer:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
    IEnumerable<TSource> second, 
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer
);
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it working?

---

**UPDATE**

`list1` and `list2` types:

```
List<Contact>
```

Where `Contact` is

```
public class Contact : EntityBase
{
    public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Email> Emails {get; set;}
}
```

`EntityBase` is

```
public class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetDBEntities<T>(ApplicationDbContext db) where T : class
    {
        return db.Set<T>();
    }

    public List<T> GetLocalEntities<T>() where T : class
    {
        var localProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var localProperty in localProperties)
        {
            var localPropertyValue = localProperty.GetValue(this);
            if (localPropertyValue != null && localPropertyValue.IsGenericList() == true)
            {
                var localPropertyValueType = localPropertyValue.GetType(); // List<object>
                var localPropertyValueTypeDecoupled = localPropertyValueType.GetGenericArguments().Single(); // List<T>
                if (localPropertyValueTypeDecoupled == typeof(T))
                {
                    return (List<T>)localPropertyValue;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Entity Types Validation Error");
    }

    public void ProcessEntityReference<T>(ApplicationDbContext db) where T : class
    {
        // T is Email
        var remoteList = this.GetDBEntities<T>(db).ToList();
        var updatedList = GetLocalEntities<T>();
        var toBeAdded = updatedList.Except(remoteList, new PropertyComparer<Guid>("ContactId"));
        var toBeDeleted = new List<object>();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ProcessEntityReferences(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        this.ProcessEntityReference<Email>(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `Except()` on a collection that have been converted to parallelEnumerable using `AsParallel()`.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the types of `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: Is list a type of `ParallelEnumerable`?

Comment: I updated the question with the types of my lists. I am not using AsParallel anywhere in the code to convert the lists.

Comment: Ya but show us how you're initializing and populating the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the same type used by your list to the Except method, in your example, you are using `Guid` but it should be of type `Contact`, also, your `Contact` class doesn't have a property called "ObjectId", try changing that for "`ContactId`", the following seems to work fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var list1 = new List<Contact>();
     list1.Add(new Contact() { ContactId = Guid.Parse("FB58F102-0CE4-4914-ABFF-ABBD3895D719") });
     list1.Add(new Contact() { ContactId = Guid.Parse("5A201238-6036-4385-B848-DEE598A3520C") });

     var list2 = new List<Contact>();
     list2.Add(new Contact() { ContactId = Guid.Parse("FB58F102-0CE4-4914-ABFF-ABBD3895D719") });

     var list3 = list1.Except(list2, new PropertyComparer<Contact>("ContactId"));

     foreach (var item in list3) 
         Console.WriteLine(item.ContactId.ToString());

     Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Contact
{
    public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private PropertyInfo _PropertyInfo;
    public PropertyComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        _PropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName,
            BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (_PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("{0} is not a property of type {1}.", propertyName, typeof(T)));
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        object propertyValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return propertyValue.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        object xValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
        object yValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(y, null);

        if (xValue == null)
        {
            return yValue == null;
        }

        return xValue.Equals(yValue);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5a201238-6036-4385-b848-dee598a3520c
```

Comment: The main problem was that `new PropertyComparer<Contact>("ContactId")` should take a type of `Contact` to match the type parameter of the lists. OP was originally using `Guid` as the type parameter which is what caused the error

Comment: I understand now that I should have used `Contact` instead of `Guid` as the type parameter, however changing it to `Contact` doesn't resolve the problem. The error text now is `Error CS1929 'List<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Except<Contact>(ParallelQuery<Contact>, ParallelQuery<Contact>, IEqualityComparer<Contact>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<Contact>'`

Comment: @devNull, same error, only type was updated. Should I create a separate question for that?

Comment: Clean your project, delete the bin folder and rebuild, also, create a new empty console project and copy paste the code from the answer. It seems to work....

Comment: @Isma, cleaned the project, vs cache, etc. Still no luck. The code mentioned works in the console project, but not in the original project. In the original project I work with generic types <T> and use reflection to iterate over the object properties to get them, but I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, though.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it addresses one of the problems and I will create another question later to seek help with the current error. Thank you!