# C# Except to compare two list

Tags: c#

If you have two lists:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "ABC", "CDE" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "ABC" };

list1.Except(list2).Any()
```

returns true

but if you do the opposite

```
list2.Except(list1).Any()
```

returns false

I thought `list2.Except(list1).Any()` should return `true` as well but I was wrong.

Is there a way to compare two list and check if there is differences in the two lists regardless of which order the items is in each list?

I know that there are several ways to do this. With a for loop or with Linq which also results in a for loop. But I am doing this on millions of lists so speed is key.

Comment: "ABC", removing both "ABC" and "CDE", leaves nothing.  So it should return false.  Can you explain why you expected it to return true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: You Can use the linked question, and check if the result is empty.  Depending on what your doing, a HashSet is the more practical method here.

Comment: Conversely, having "ABC" and "CDE", and removing "ABC", leaves one element ("CDE").  So `Any()` returns true.

Comment: `list1.Except(list2).Any()` => true, but `list2.Except(list1).Any()` => False.

Comment: list1.ToHashSet().SymmetricExceptWith(list2).Any() seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Imagine you have lists {"ABC", "DEF"} and {"DEF", "GHI"}.  Then the order matters as one will give you "ABC" which is in the first list but not the second and the other way gives you "GHI" which is in the second list but not the first.

Comment: @Addeladde please [edit] or delete the post. It is very unclear what posts asks for and especially how `list1.ToHashSet().SymmetricExceptWith(list2).Any() ` can be an answer...

Comment: Have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Sets lets you compare 2 lists:

```
HashSet<string> list1 = new HashSet<string>() { "ABC", "CDE" };
HashSet<string> list2 = new HashSet<string>() { "ABC" };
bool IsProperSubsetOf = list1.IsProperSubsetOf(list2);
bool IsProperSupersetOf = list1.IsProperSupersetOf(list2);
bool IsSubsetOf = list1.IsSubsetOf(list2);
bool IsSupersetOf = list1.IsSupersetOf(list2);
bool SetEquals = list1.SetEquals(list2);
```

Comment: does not answer the question

Comment: The question was this: Is there a way to compare two list and check for differences regardless of which order the items is in each list?

Comment: It should be noted that using `HashSets` can change the behavior versus `List` if the original `List` contained duplicate items.  If the lists are `{"A", "A", "B"}` and `{"A", "B"}`, the difference between the lists is "A".  The hashset solution will say there are no differences.

Comment: Nevertheless, with all remarks and side notes a fine alternative.