# C# How to filter list of type T to return only new data

Tags: c#, list, filter

Im trying to make a filter function in my system so i can call this function to just filter duplicates. After 2 days of trying im getting frustrated because i cant manage to make it work. To be completely honest i dont even know if im doing it right or if its even possible.

The ways it works is that i call the "Filter" function from a other function. The filter function has 2 parameters. 1 is the existing list of items. 2 is the list with new  data. This is how i call the function

```
List<RdwDamageTable> Existing = await _context.RdwDamageTable.ToListAsync();
List<RdwDamageTable> Data = jsonArray.ToObject<List<RdwDamageTable>>();
List<RdwDamageTable> ToInsert = Sys.BaseFunctions.FilterDuplicate(Existing , Data);
```

The Filter function now looks like this.

```
public static List<T> FilterDuplicate<T>(List<T> Existing, List<T> New)
{
    return null;
}
```

Again i want see if the New list contains new items wich Existing doesnt have so i can return a list of new objects.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: Except? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System.Linq; // needed at the top somewhere
// ...
public static List<T> FilterDuplicate<T>(List<T> Existing, List<T> New)
    => New.Except(Existing).ToList();
```

Comment: for some reasons this doesnt work. i tried this and the filtered list still contains te old data

Comment: @NickGlas what are your equality semantics? are they the same objects? or different objects that simply look similar?

Comment: Hey  @MarcGravell The list are the same. The only thing what is different is that i load the existing data from a database. So the only thing extra would be the id field wouldnt it ?

Comment: @Nick that isn't how object equality works. If they aren't he exact same object **instance**, then you'll need to define equality yourself, separately. That involves overriding Equals and GetHashCode, and ideally implementing IEquatable-T