# Comparing every row of two lists of objects for a property and create new object

Tags: vb.net

Here is what I am trying to do:

Compare every row of compareList with every row of refList

```
    ----- Do you find 'Leistungscode' of compareList in refList?
     ----- Yes--> Ignore
     ----- No--> New Entry, add to resutList
```

My problem is that with my for each loop, it creates a new entry every time when `Leistungscode` doesn't match up, but I need to look through the whole `refList` first and then add it to the list if I haven't found it. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Here is what I tried:

```
For Each rowCompare In compareList
    For Each rowRef In refList
        If rowCompare.Leistungscode.CompareTo(rowRef.Leistungscode) = 0 Then

        Else
            resultList.Add(New ISAACService(rowCompare.Leistungscode, rowCompare.K_Art, rowCompare.UANR, rowCompare.Ueberbegriff, rowCompare.Benennung, rowCompare.Anzahl, rowCompare.Einheit, rowCompare.Einzelkosten, rowCompare.Summencode))
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you should not use `CompareTo`. `CompareTo` does extra work determining position. You just need an equals sign.

The empty `If`, with code only in the else, can be corrected by adding `Not` to the if.

The real key here is `Exit For`. Once you find an instance with no match the instance is added to the `resultList` so we want to stop searching at that point to avoid duplicate entries in the `resultList`. `Exit For` only exits the inner `For` loop. The outer loop will continue with the next element of the `commpareList`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each rowCompare In compareList
        For Each rowRef In refList
            If Not rowCompare.Leistungscode = rowRef.Leistungscode Then
                resultList.Add(New ISAACService(rowCompare.Leistungscode, rowCompare.K_Art, rowCompare.UANR, rowCompare.Ueberbegriff, rowCompare.Benennung, rowCompare.Anzahl, rowCompare.Einheit, rowCompare.Einzelkosten, rowCompare.Summencode))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(resultList.Count.ToString)
End Sub
```